# Mincha after plag hamincha without minyan

Tags: halacha, maariv, evening-night, mincha-afternoon-prayer, leil-shabbat

If on Friday night somebody begins Mincha before Plag byechidus, but ends after Plag & then would like to daven Maariv after Plag with a minyan, would that be permitted? This question is based on two factors. The 1st is can we bedieved rely on the fact that he started before Plag. The 2nd factor is that one of the hetters of davening Mincha & Maariv both after Plag is that of Tircha Detzibbura, (Being burdensome to the congregation to have to come back) but here the individual davened Beyichudus, but he did come to a shul, just there was not 10 people yet, so would Tircha Detzibbura apply? (This is not My Shaila rather my edits)

Comment: Are there any other restrictions on the case? Why don't they just daven maariv bezman?

Comment: How is this different than the regular question of tarti desatri?

Comment: This is a real case situation. It happened last Friday Night. They continued with Kabbalat Shabbat (without a minyan) and then (after a minyan was formed) they davened Maariv still before Nightfall. My view is that it is entirely tarti desatri. By davening Mincha after Plag Hamincha without a minyan, they should not have davened Maariv with the minyan, as the conditions of doing Maariv early had not been met.

Comment: I don't understand why it matters that they davened mincha without a minyan. Right now they are left with the option of maariv with a minyan but tarti desatri, or leaving and having no minyan. So you're left with the regular question of the 7PM mincha/maariv. BTW welcome to the site! Please consider registering your account to be able to fully participate around the site. Also feel free to [edit] your question if you want to clarify something.

Comment: Surely the only reason why Maariv is allowed to be davened early is if it is combined with Mincha, both of which require a minyan, otherwise what is the justification of davening Maariv on its own - with or without a minyan - if it is not even Sunset let alone nightfall?

Comment: The justification would be that right now you have the option of minyan via tarti desatri or no minyan. This is exactly the regular case where some say that since if you let people go home there won't be a minyan, it is better to daven with a minyan via tarti desatri than no minyan.

Comment: when did you start Mincha? If it was before Plag, there is no question

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Well...less of a question. Some hold that even multi-day tarti desatri is no good and nowadays you can never daven maariv after plag ever.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Also it might depend on when they finished mincha, not just when they started.

Comment: Shmuel, Mincha was started after Plag Hamincha.

Comment: @Daniel if you have information that clarifies the question, please edit it into the question instead of merely adding it in comments.

Comment: Can we clarify if even the private mincha was after 7:45?

Comment: @Menachem "Shmuel, Mincha was started after Plag Hamincha. – Daniel Jun 24 at 20:32"

Comment: @DoubleAA: I'm just unclear if "the decision is taken to daven Mincha privately" means that 8 of them prayed before Plag HaMincha, or if after Plag HaMincha they saw there would be no minyan so they decided to pray privately. And, did the other two show up before they prayed privately, but after the decision was taken to do so, or did the private prayer take place before the other two showed up?

Answer (score 1):

[Don't forget to CYLOR](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17262/mincha-after-plag-hamincha-without-minyan#comment38924_17262), but the Ktzos Hashulchan ([Siman 77 in the Badei Hahulchan sif katan 17 and 18](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7722&pgnum=57)) writes that one should pray Maariv earlier on Shabbos night, but one is not allowed to pray before Tzeis if he davened Mincha after Plag. However, if one did, he is Yotzei Maariv. (He must still say Shema again after Tzeis)

Comment: I don't see how this addresses the question, in which they said _mincha before p'lag_.

Comment: @msh210 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17262/mincha-after-plag-hamincha-without-minyan/17455#comment38995_17262 but I agree the question is convoluted and too real-life IMO. If you read through the comments you might see how I tried to figure out what's going on. FWIU he's asking if the heter for tarti desatri is predicated on mincha being davened right then as well with a minyan. Perhaps NARQ for now, but eventually I think there should be two questions: a general tarti destari Friday night, and whether early maariv minyanim are tied to an adjacent mincha.

Comment: BTW I think his notion that it does need mincha with a minyan is based on too literal a read of the lines in poskim that say "they are already gathered for mincha and it's a torech to gather them again so we daven tarti desatri".

Comment: @msh210 see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17262/mincha-after-plag-hamincha-without-minyan/17455#comment38995_17262

Answer (score -2):

Aruch ha-Shulchan permits this.

Comment: He discusses the case where mincha was davened beyechidut and then they want to daven maariv betzibbur??

Comment: Also please cite the relevant simanim.

Comment: I am not sure why having a minyan justifies davening Maariv before Shkiah if none of the conditions have been met. The only reason you are permitted to daven Maariv before Shkiah is if it is combined with Mincha with a minyan (which should ideally be davened before Plag Hamincha). You can't daven Maariv during Mincha Katenna or Mincha Gedolah and neither can you daven it in isolation - with or without a minyan - before Shkiah. Surely?

Comment: @Daniel Can you please explain why you think maariv needs to be attached to mincha and not in 'isolation' as you say? I have never heard of such a requirement and can't think of any reason why it should be so.

Comment: It needs to be attached in order to justify davening Maariv before Shkiah. This is surely at the heart of the debate between Rabbi Yehuda and the ta'anaim?

Comment: @Daniel I don't see why that is surely at the heart of anything. RY and the Sages are arguing about the boundary line for the latest mincha but I see no reason why according to RY 10 men can't daven mincha at 12:30 PM and then maariv at 5:00 PM (on a 6:00 AM - 6:00 PM day). They have successfully placed each prayer on the opposite side of the boundary. What's the problem?

Comment: But if Shkiah isn't till 9.08pm then how can it be possible to convene a minyan for Maariv at around 7.55pm on its own? The early davening of Maariv before Shkiah, let alone Tzeit Hakochovim, is predicated on Mincha? No? And my understanding was that if you daven Mincha past Plag Hamincha as an individual, then you can't daven Maariv, even with a minyan, until Tzeit Hacochovim.

Comment: @Daniel You are just repeating yourself but still not sourcing anything (nor are you pinging me by using @ and my username).

Comment: @DoubleAA All the sources I have found all assume that you have a minyan for both Mincha and Maariv, which you intend to daven side by side using the Plag Hamincha argument of Rabbi Yehuda and the Ta'anaim. However, I have not seen any source that suggests that it is permissible to just convene a minyan to daven Maariv before Shkiah. Let's assume that Mincha had been davened at Mincha Katena, would you be allowed to convene a minyan for Maariv before Shkiah? The sources do not imply this.

Comment: @Daniel If that was the only possibility for a minyan and you would not be able to convene everyone later, then yes you could convene a minyan just for maariv. What sources imply otherwise?

Comment: @DoubleAA, none of the sources, to my knowledge, unless you can demonstrate otherwise, refer to this sort of scenario. Surely, you cannot just convene a minyan and daven Maariv if it is not the appropriate time to do so, however convenient it might be and it may be more appropriate to daven alone.